# Как отобразить команду в номеронабирателе Swift 3

Tags: swift

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста!
Как отобразить команду в номеро-набирателе в Swift 3

Например: `*1111111#`

[image: Нудно отобразить комаду]

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
guard let number = URL(string: "tel://" + number) else { 
  fatalError("URL must not be nil")
}

UIApplication.shared.open(number)
```

Comment: "Вы не можете набрать номер, содержащий * или # символов. Apple не разрешает их в строке набора по соображениям безопасности."

Answer (score 0):

Вы не можете отобразить в номеронабирателе что хотите. Вы можете совершить телефонный звонок на номер без символов `* #` до iOS 11.

Начиная с iOS 11 можно использовать и `* #`, но появится диалоговое окно и пользователь выберет совершить набор или отменить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за информацию! Буду знать.